# finding minimum element of array using recursion

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, min

I have coded the following program to find the minimum value element from an array using recursion. However the program keeps on showing me the answer as 1000

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

int getminElement(int []);
int size;

int main(){

    int min;
    int i;
    int a[10]={12,6,-24,78,43,3,22,45,40};

    min=getminElement(a);

    printf("Smallest element of an array is: %d",min);

    return 0;
}

int getminElement(int a[]){

    static int i=0,min =1000;

    if(i < size){
        if(min > a[i])
            min=a[i];
        i++;
        getminElement(a);
    }

    return min;
}
```

Comment: Decide first, you want minimum or maximum?

Comment: Maybe also decide what to do for empty arrays (i.e. `size` == 0). If you consider that case undefined (an `assert` might be good here) you could define that the minimum of a singleton array (i.e. `size == 1`) is the only element. Otherwise, it's the smaller value of the first array element and the minimum of the remainder of the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not set the `size` variable. Since `size` is a global variable, it is automatically getting initialized to `0`.

So when this condition is reached for the first time

```
if(i < size)
```

It fails, thus returning `min`, which is `1000`

---

Do the following

```
int max;
int i;
int a[10]={12,6,-24,78,43,3,22,45,40};

size = 10;
```

Or, to make it better.

```
int max;
int i;
int a[10]={12,6,-24,78,43,3,22,45,40};

size = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);
```

---

As discussed in the comments, there is another error in your code. You ignore the return value of the function call inside the `if` block.

You should use that to return the value back to the calling function. Something like,

```
if(i < size)
{
    if(min > a[i])
        min=a[i];
    i++;
    return getminElement(a);
}
```

---

As pointed out by some people, your code is a little confusing, so I'll post a simpler one, without `static` and `global` variables. Do try to understand it, and post comment if you find it difficult.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

int getminElement(int [], int, int);

int main()
{

    int min;
    int i;
    int a[10]={12,6,-24,78,43,3,22,45,-40};

    printf("Smallest element of an array is: %d", getminElement(a, 0, sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)));

    return 0;
}

int getminElement(int a[], int index, int size)
{
    int min = 9999;

    if(index < size)
        min = getminElement(a, index + 1, size);

    if(a[index] < min)
        return a[index];
    else
        return min;

}
```

Comment: @haccks, are you talking about the `max-min` thing?

Comment: I am talking about `getminElement` function.

Comment: @haccks, I didn't get you.

Comment: @Haris; Look at the statement `getminElement(a);` in `getminElement` function. Its return type is `int`.

Comment: @haccks, you're saying it should be `static int`?

Comment: @haccks, May be I am being a little stupid. But I still can't find the error. :(

Comment: @haccks, the return is not received in the call inside the `if` block?

Comment: @Haris; Yes. Exactly.

Comment: In `getminElement(a);` the value returned by that recursion is ignored.

Comment: @haccks Both `return getminelement(a);` and simply `getminelement(a);` will perform the same way in this case as `min` and `i` are `static int`s.

Comment: @CoolGuy, Yes, but it should not be ignored, I agree with haccks.

Comment: @Haris Yes. I agree. The OP's code is confusing. I suggest you write a better way of doing this in your answer.

Comment: You don't need the `index` argument. Instead, you can increment the `a` pointer and decrement `size`. That way, you can define `if (size == 1) return a[0]; int min = getminElement(a + 1, size - 1); return a[0] < min ? a[0] : min;`.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe, I think that would be a little to advanced for a beginner. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another recursive version

```
int getminElement(int min, int *p, int size) {
   if (*p < min) min = *p;    // set min to minimum(*p, min)
   if (size < 1) return min;  // no more elements to see, return min
   return getminElement(min, p+1, size-1); // recursive call
}
```

called

```
int numelem = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);
int minimum = getminElement(1000, a, numelem);
```

assuming the minimum in *a* being >= 1000, as you did.

Here the *getminElement* function examine all elements of *a*, via the pointer *p* to *int* which is incremented at each recursive call, size being decremented.

The function being called recursively with the current min, the next element to examine, the remaining size.